# How to troubleshoot a feature designed to replace the SmallSearchInputBox?

Tags: feature

I have been trying to create a feature which replaces the SmallSearchInputBox delegate in SharePoint 2010.

I have a new control which I placed in ~/controltemplates and created an element and feature xml.

In the debug mode of VS2010, I can see the site collection feature and activate it but nothing changes to the search area. I also tried farm scope but no difference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This delegate control takes a single control, so you need to ensure that the sequence is less than 25 (the default control) to override it. Make the sequence 20 or something. Also make sure the feature is Site scoped.

It might be worth double checking that the page you are loading actually contains the SmallSearchInputBox delegate control. It's easy to miss this kind of thing. I should know.

Answer (score 0):

If changing your sequence id (as SPDoctor suggests), can you post your code?

Conveniently enough, MSDN's sample article on delegate controls deals with the SmallSearchInputBox. You can find that link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms463169.aspx). **Note the comments at the bottom of the article as they have a few errors published.**